# Declare a scalar variable which takes in every row of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to declare a variable which takes in every row of my RDD and does some calculations and gives me an output.

The calculations would include that it will return the first day of the week, unless the RDD falls into a new month, it would return first day of that month.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
             (
                 RDD date
             )

INSERT INTO @tbl
    SELECT RDD 
    FROM tableA

DECLARE @testdate date

SELECT @testdate = RDD
FROM @tbl

SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(@testdate) = MONTH(DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(weekday, @testdate), @testdate))
            THEN DATEADD(day, 1-DATEPART(weekday, @testdate), @testdate)
            ELSE DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @testdate), 0)  
    END AS FDW, 
    RDD,
    BPN, 
FROM
    tableA
WHERE
    RDD IS NOT NULL  
GROUP BY
    RDD, BPN
```

I tried the following and received the following output:

| FDW | RDD |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-27 00:00:00:000 | 2024-06-19 |
| 2023-08-27 00:00:00:000 | 2024-02-22 |

This is strange because when I execute the following:

```
DECLARE @TESTDATE DATE = '2024-06-19'

 

select
  case when month(@testdate) = month(dateadd(day,1-datepart(weekday,@testdate),@testdate))
       then dateadd(day,1-datepart(weekday,@testdate),@testdate)
       else DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,@testdate),0)  
  end
```

My output is 2024-06-16 as expected (first day of the week, the week starts from Sunday in my case).

So what is wrong with the above query? Why is the case expression not working there?

Comment: umm, you use @testdata in your select from the table. select
case when month(RDD) ie. the column from the table, not variable?

Comment: The title contradicts itself - a column doesn't have rows, a scalar value only contains *one* value (that's what `scalar` means), not multiple values. It would be better if you explained what you want and showed sample data and expected output, not how you think the solution will look like

Comment: In any case, to calculate a single value from a column's values you need `GROUP BY` and some aggregate function. `GROUP BY` is the only thing that combined multiple result rows into one. ... wait

Comment: You already asked the same thing twice yesterday. Why don't you just use one of the answers you already got? `SELECT GREATEST(DATETRUNC(month,RDD),DATETRUNC(week,RDD)) FROM TableA` will give you the start of week, or month if the month has changed. After that, what

Comment: that is why I have declared a table variable. when I select RDD from @tbl it gives me an output of all RDD present in my tableA.. What approach do you suggest ?

Comment: You created a table variable but never use it. `@testdata` contains only *one* value, probably the last one. Although, as there's no ORDER BY, it could be any one. `What approach` to do what? You haven't explained what you want after several days. People already explained how you can get the start of week you want. What do you want in *this* question? Post an actual table schema, test data (multiple rows) and the result you want, so people can write a query that produces it.

Comment: If you can't use the functions available in your SQL Server version, say so explicitly, so people can test other solutions

Comment: This sounds strongly like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Is there any reason you keep deleting questions and creating new ones? You are probably heading for an automatic question ban by the bots.

Answer (score 0):

As I can guess from your question, you want to get first day of week for every date of your table `tableA`, but start of month for every first date of month? Something like this?:

```
select
  case
    when datediff(month,lag(RDD) over (order by RDD),RDD)>0 then DATEFROMPARTS(year(RDD),month(RDD),1) 
    else dateadd(day,1-datepart(weekday,RDD),RDD)
  end FDW,
  RDD,
  BPN
from
  TableA
```

Or, maybe, you need a starting date of week, but if it's in other month, query must return start of month?:

```
select
  (select max(DT) from (values(DATEFROMPARTS(year(RDD),month(RDD),1)) ,(dateadd(day,1-datepart(weekday,RDD),RDD))) SL(DT)) FDW,
  RDD,
  BPN
from
  TableA
```